# use argument containing spaces in bash

Tags: bash

I know about escaping, quoting and stuff, but still have a problem.

I you have a script containing "cd $1", and call it with an argument containing spaces, cd will always return an error message - it stops at the first space and can't find the directory. I tried protecting the arguments in every way :

```
ls -l
+-rwx... script
+drwx... dir with spaces/
cat script
+cd $1

script dir with spaces
+cd: dir: no such file or directory

script "dir with spaces"
+cd: dir: no such file or directory

script dir\ with\ spaces
+cd: dir\: no such file or directory
```

but none will work.

I feel like I'm missing the obvious, thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the expansion of `"$1"` to prevent it from being word split as well as quoting the string passed to the script to prevent it from being word-split.

So

```
$ cat script.sh
cd -- "$1"
$ ./script.sh "dir with spaces"
```

Edit: As gniourf_gniourf correctly pointed out using `--` as the first argument to `cd` prevents problems should paths ever start with `-`.

Comment: I must have skipped the cd "$1" with protected argument case in my debug check-list... Thank you for making me feel stupid again ^^

Comment: The answer is almost always "use more quotes". =)

Comment: Even better: `cd -- "$1"` so that OP won't come back in a few days/weeks/months/years with the question _use argument starting with a hyphen in bash_.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes on the variable

```
 cd "$1"
```